# Lubuntu Installation won't recognize Windows

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on a recently acquired Dell Latitude E6220.  I have been running Lubuntu 16 on my old (defunct) laptop for almost three years.  New machine has Windows 10 installed, and I don't want to erase it; but I can't get the installer to provide the "install alongside" option. None of the forums I have visited seem to have this bug resolved, but I am hopeful someone might have answers, as Lubuntu is really the distro I want to stay with. I have turned off fast startup.  My live usb was created by Universal USB Installer. Windows 10 boots in legacy mode.   Thanks for any help!

Comment: May want to disable  "fast boot" in Windows power options to make sure it is shut down properly and not hibernated. Also, there is no screenshot of Gparted or any info about partition layout, so it is not easy to help.

Comment: If BIOS based have you used all 4 primary partitions? More info on fast startup which sets hibernation flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: When referring to a bug, please provide launchpad bug ID so I can look up the bug you refer to. I would assume your issue however is what oldfred suggested.

Comment: Thank you.  Disabling fast boot was the first thing I did, since all directions mentioned that.  I don't know how to take a screen shot in Gparted--but I haven't been using Gparted for any of this so far.  I have tried repartitioning the C drive in Windows before launching the Lubuntu installer.  I haven't yet tried "something else," as I am not confident with that option.  The installer says I have Windows 10, but does not offer the "Install alongside" option.  The first option is "erase."

Comment: In some situation, a side by side installation is not possible, for example with MBR and four primary partitions. When presented with installation options, select the last one called Something else, and take a screenshot of the layout - Alt+Prt Sc. Alternatively, you can snap a screenshot of the disk manager in Windows.